# Why getElementById returns null despite of print ID of element?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, cognos

I need to get element from site. I get id in of this element in console, but when I try to get this element (i need it to use in eventListener) I have null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const selectedDate = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedDate');
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate());
currentDate = currentDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);

var ocr = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");
var datePrompt=ocr.prompt.getControlByName('launch_date_start');
const controls = ocr.prompt.getControls();
const inputId = controls[0]._id_;

const inputEle = document.getElementById(`${inputId}`);


console.log('ÍD', inputId) // here console print me particular ID
console.log('Input ELE',inputEle) // here it shows null

</script>
```

Comment: show what result did you get in `console.log('ÍD', inputId)` Are you sure that your `inputId` without `#`?

Comment: could it be that the Javascript loads before the HTML - which means that, while your logic is correct, the element itself has not appeared yet to be "get" ? A way to solve this is to put the <script> tag at the end of the HTML. Also please ensure that the exact Id is present within the HTML.

Comment: have you tried just using the inputID variable as the argument for .getElementById? Try removing the ‘${}’ characters.

Comment: @Greg-- ÍD N0x17ab7c40x0x1805a744RS
VM2944:14

Comment: @HeathSmith without $ also the same

Comment: `N0x17ab7c40x0x1805a744RS VM2944:14` is id with space? and `:` symbol? does element with this id exist?

Comment: @Greg-- yes, it is input label for time prompt set in report, it exist.   id is only :N0x17ab7c40x0x1805a744RS

Comment: this id give some script?

Comment: @Greg-- it is cognos element

Comment: if you just put in console `document.getElementById('N0x17ab7c40x0x1805a744RS VM2944:14')` what did you get?

Comment: @Greg-- The Id is diffrent every time when I run report

Comment: can you update your question with a sample of the html code generating the element id’s? that may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @ruddnisrus are you sure that when you load script the element with this id already exist in DOM? did you try run script after DOM loaded or window loaded?

Comment: The situation is that I run report in HTML. then I need to provide date changing ability, and the date is back to current date after refresh. Im not sure if this element existing..

Comment: @Greg-- maybe I can get this element by parent?

Comment: At the risk of starting over... What version of Cognos is the question about?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using the samples and share the report spec?

Comment: @dougp bundle.js?v=11.0.13.1:12 Timer 'rsperf: total_RunReport' does not exist
_iframe_onload @ bundle.js?v=11.0.13.1:12
VM1480:15 ÍD N0x9039dc0x0x184f9544RS
VM1480:16 Input ELE null
VM1480:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: look at  ÍD N0x9039dc0x0x184f9544RS and  Input ELE null, I have this object, the id is generated with all report run, so it exist, but it doesn't fetch object....